# Back to top of a ngIf section

Tags: angular

I have an Angular SPA, page contains either listing of records or edit a record section (includes history of editing as well). Initial state is to show list of records.

Because some record has long history of editing, so placing a *Back to top of Editing* will make it easier to use. HTML5 supports `#top`, right? Well, it actually toggles back to non-editing mode shows list of records :(

HTML below:

```
<div *ngIf="editMode">
  <a id="top"></a>
  record detailed content here
  <hr>
  long history of record editing here
  <a href="#top">Back to top of Editing</a><!-- Nope, it actually toggles back to non-editing mode shows list of records -->
<div>
 
<div *ngIf="!editMode">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let rec of listRec">
  ...
  <input type=button (click)="switchToEditMode()">Edit</input>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

.TS:

```
editMode: boolean = false;
...
switchToEditMode() { editMode=true; ...}
```

**Update, this is how it works following @RedJandal suggestion using Manual Scrolling,** add this to HTML

```
<span #myTop id="myTop"></span>
<button (click)="toMyTop()">go to Top</button>
```

add this to TS

```
@ViewChild("myTop") myTop: ElementRef;
toMyTop()
  {
    const targetElement = this.myTop.nativeElement;
    targetElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  }
```

Note, to use `<a>` in place of `<button>`, important to remove `href=#<anything>`

Comment: <a href="#top> looks like you forgot to close quotes?

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla It's a pseudo code explaining, updated, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using an anchor tag the page is being refreshed, that is why it toggles back to non-editing mode.

### Automatic Scrolling

Since Angular v6, there is the new `anchorScrolling` option for the `RouterModule`. You can set it in the module's import:

```
imports: [
  ...,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {anchorScrolling: 'enabled'})
```

With this, Angular will automatically scroll to the element with the id of the given fragment.

⚠️ However, this does not work when the data is loaded asynchronously, see this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547). ⚠️

---

### Manual Scrolling

[Smooth scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Parameters) is not yet possible via the `RouterModule`, but you can do it manually:

Get your target e.g. with `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild('pageInfo') pageInfo: ElementRef;
```

Call `scrollIntoView` on the `nativeElement`:

```
const targetElement = this.pageInfo.nativeElement
targetElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
```

Comment: Would you mind explain the difference between auto and manual scrolling besides coding?

Comment: With Automatic scrolling you just have to turn the feature on and anchor tags will work. However as I mentioned there is currently an issue with async data. With manual you are manually defining the element to scroll to. This will give you more control, but it means more work

Comment: Opted for Manual Scrolling, add this to HTML `<span #myTop id="myTop"></span>`, this to TS `@ViewChild("myTop") myTop: ElementRef; toMyTop()
  {
    const targetElement = this.myTop.nativeElement;
    targetElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  }` Right after go back to top, it refresh the page back to Listing mode.

Comment: @Jeb50 can you confirm you removed the href="#top" from the link?

Comment: Awesome, that's it!